# Change PDF out put file name dynamically in oracle reports

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

Please guide how to change output PDF file name at run time

I am using below code in after parameter form trigger but its not working :

:DESNAME := 'INVOICE_'||:P_CLIENT||'.PDF';

Please guide me..

Comment: what do you mean with "not working"? An error? An unwanted result? Plese have a look  at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: sorry, can u please guide me  how to change output file  name, at run time.
When i

Comment: When i generates PDF file, the file must have named be as the name which i  set in trigger right?.I tried the above code its not displaying  the name which have set in trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which Reports version you use; up to 6i program that is used to *create* reports was called "Reports Builder", while later versions use name "Reports Developer". Doesn't really matter, but - if you open Reports Online Help System (navigate to "Help" menu) and search for DESNAME, you'll find which executables can be used to set DESNAME's value. **RWBUILDER** is **not** among them. And yes, *rwbuilder* is Builder's and/or Developer's EXE name.

It means that you're out of luck, at least regarding the way you're trying to set DESNAME's value. You can't set it in any of Reports' triggers. I mean, you *can*, but it won't take any effect.

However, if you call the report from, for example, a form developed by Oracle Forms, then you'd use **RWRUN** which **can** specify DESNAME value and yes, you can *dynamically* create it.

For some more info, do read Help I pointed you to previously.

Comment: I am working on oracle forms 11g and Oracle reports 11g. Developing reports in oracle reports builder 11g. I need to study these RWBUILDER,RWRUN etc. 

Thanks for info. I will try this too and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Among several ways of calling Reports from Forms, i can suggest you to use adding RP2RRO.pll to your Form :
[image]

And then, add parameters related to this `pll` :
[image]

And you may call your reports by this code :

```
 Pr_Print_Rp2Rro('Rep_Invoice','|Prm1|Prm2|','|'||:Prm1||'|'||:Prm2||'|','no','INVOICE_'||:P_Client||'.PDF');
```

assuming you have two user defined parameters namely : `Prm1` & `Prm2`. And `Pr_Print_Rp2Rro` is a procedure with the following code :

```
Procedure Pr_Print_Rp2Rro( 
                           i_rep_name  varchar2, 
                           i_prm_name  varchar2, 
                           i_prm_val   varchar2,
                           i_param_frm varchar2, -- 'Yes','No'                            
                           i_desname   varchar2,
                           i_destype   varchar2 default 'FILE'
                         ) Is
  plist          ParamList; 
  arr_prm_name owa.vc_arr; 
  arr_prm_val  owa.vc_arr;  
Begin
  plist := Get_Parameter_List('REPPARAM');
 if not Id_Null(plist) then
  Destroy_Parameter_List('REPPARAM');
 end if; 
  plist := Create_Parameter_List('REPPARAM');  
  Add_Parameter(plist, 'PARAMFORM', Text_Parameter,  i_param_frm); 
  Rp2rro.SetDestype(i_destype); 
  Rp2rro.SetDesname(i_desname);       
 for i in 1..100
 loop 
     arr_prm_name(i) := substr(i_prm_name,instr(i_prm_name,'|',1,i)+1,instr(i_prm_name,'|',1,1+i)-instr(i_prm_name,'|',1,i)-1);
     arr_prm_val(i)  := substr(i_prm_val,instr(i_prm_val,'|',1,i)+1,instr(i_prm_val,'|',1,1+i)-instr(i_prm_val,'|',1,i)-1);   
    if length(arr_prm_name(i)) > 0 then
   Add_Parameter( plist, arr_prm_name(i) , Text_Parameter, arr_prm_val(i) );
  end if;
 end loop; 
  Rp2rro.Rp2rro_Run_Product(Reports, i_rep_name, Synchronous, Runtime,Filesystem, plist,null);
End ;
```

As you may have noticed this procedure contains a method `Rp2rro.SetDesname(i_desname)` which you could use and manage your task to create Report names spesific to your customer, unless you set your `Destype` parameter as `CACHE`.

Comment: Thanks for information,i will try it and let you know.